# Fair semaphore with/or thread-safe queue in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

From reading the docs and questions/answers here, there is no "fair" semaphore in Python, which means that under stress conditions, it becomes likely that some threads will starve.

In [this thread (fair-semaphore-in-python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158442/fair-semaphore-in-python), the answer suggests to use a queue of events, where each time, the thread that ends its work will signal to the next thread that it's safe to start. The problem with it is that the last thread will wait forever to signal to the next thread, which does not exist and will thus never come.

My question is, whether there is a way to implement a fair semaphore in Python? Are the `threading.queue` objects fair? (since if so, then it should be possible to reimplement the `acquire()` method to wait until it reaches the end of the queue and thus enforce fairness)

Comment: Re, "Are the `threading.queue` objects fair?" That's not optional behavior for queues. If something is called a "queue", then that means, _by definition_, that objects come out in the same order that they went in.

Comment: Re, "[is there] a way to implement a fair semaphore in Python?" Python is a fully-general programming language. And, it's got locks and condition variables.  I don't have time to design it for you, but if you have locks and condition variables (Or, if you have not-necessarily-fair semaphores), then you can build on that to implement pretty much any higher-level inter-thread synchronization and communication that you want.

Comment: @SolomonSlow but different threads are going to try to add items to the queue. The question regarding queue fairness was in other words, whether threads cannot starve while waiting to be able to add their items to the queue - whether the access to the queue is not in random order

Comment: OK, so it sounds like your higher-level goal is, you want a fixed-size, blocking queue; and you want it to be "fair" in the sense that, if one thread is blocked in `q.put(a)`, and then another thread subsequently is blocked in `q.put(b)`, you want a guarantee that the `a` always will go in to the queue before the `b` goes in. Is that right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem do you hope to solve with that? What bad thing will your program do if one producer thread gets blocked for a longer-than-normal amount of time?

Comment: I want a locking mechanism that will guarantee that the thread that called `acquire()` first will get access first. When the access is given randomly to any of the threads that called `acquire` so far, the chance of starvation becomes higher when there are many threads for long time. Suppose that the chance of starvation is very low at a single point, e.g. `10^-5`. Along time, the chance of any starvation will be `[1 - (10^-5)]^n` where `n` is the number of points in time. You will sometime have real likelihood > 0 to have a thread starvation

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point. Are you trying to solve a problem in some actual program? (i.e., do you have a program that fails to perform some task in a satisfactory way?) Or, is your interest in fair locking purely academic? The answer to your original question still is Yes, You can implement a fair lock in any programming language that gives you the basics--simple mutexes and condition variables. But, I still don't have time to design it for you. Personally, I have never wanted a fair lock. That would be a red flag for me, suggesting that I should re-think my design.

Comment: It is not for academic use, but for a real server application that gets a lot of requests, in a load that lasts for a few hours. It uses the GPU, so only one thread (request) can really be analyzed at a time, which is enforced using a semaphore. Yet, after a long time, some thread would starve which would cause its request to eventually fail on timeout. The more time the load lasts, the lower is the probability to not have some starving thread. I can design a fair semaphore by myself if I have a fair queue to use within

Comment: IMO, it would be a mistake to try to make threads go one-at-a-time like that. I would have just one dedicated thread for the GPU. I would let other threads put tasks into a blocking queue, the GPU thread would perform the tasks in the same order that they went into the queue, and then it would signal the the waiting, other thread each time it completed a task.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, I think I'll try it. It sounds reasonable and elegant